# opengl interleaving vbo not rendering to screen

Tags: c, opengl, vbo

the opengl documentation say to interleave data and use stride and offset to pack multiple vertex attributes into one buffer.

The api [reference here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) list this format.

```
void glVertexAttribPointer( GLuint index,
    GLint size,
    GLenum type,
    GLboolean normalized,
    GLsizei stride,
    const GLvoid * pointer);
```

I am having some trouble getting things to render using this format. I can render a scene using three separate buffers and putting the data in there but using one buffer I am rendering a blank screen.

data structure.

```
typedef struct {
    vec3 angles;
    GLshort vertex_count;
    GLfloat vertices[12];
    GLfloat colors[16];
    GLshort indices[6];
    GLfloat tex_coords[8];
} cg_sprite;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &big_vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &big_vbo);
glGenBuffers(1, &big_ibo);

glBindVertexArray(big_vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_vbo_size, big_v_buff, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_ibo_total, big_i_buff,
             GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                      (GLvoid*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                      (GLvoid*)(4 * sizeof(float)));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                      (GLvoid*)(7 * sizeof(float)));


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

after setting up my vbo like that, I do this in the rendering loop. After I translate, rotate and scale my vertices on the cpu, i pack them into the giant buffers like this:

```
cg_sprite_back_2_front(sprites, sprite_count);
for (int i = 0; i < sprite_count; i++) {
    //--------------- start packing data into buffers----------------
    sp = sprites[i];

    // v0
    idx = 0;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov0.x;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov0.y;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov0.z;

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[0];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[1];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[2];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[3];

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[0];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[1];

    // v1
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov1.x;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov1.y;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov1.z;

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[4];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[5];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[6];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[7];

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[2];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[3];

    // v2
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov2.x;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov2.y;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov2.z;

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[8];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[9];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[10];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[11];

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[4];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[5];

    // v3
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov3.x;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov3.y;
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = ov3.z;

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[12];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[13];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[14];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->colors[15];

    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[6];
    big_v_buff[(i * 36) + idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[7];

    idx = 0;
    big_i_buff[(i * 6) + idx++] = i * 4 + sp->quad->indices[0];
    big_i_buff[(i * 6) + idx++] = i * 4 + sp->quad->indices[1];
    big_i_buff[(i * 6) + idx++] = i * 4 + sp->quad->indices[2];

    big_i_buff[(i * 6) + idx++] = i * 4 + sp->quad->indices[3];
    big_i_buff[(i * 6) + idx++] = i * 4 + sp->quad->indices[4];
    big_i_buff[(i * 6) + idx++] = i * 4 + sp->quad->indices[5];
    idx = 0;
  }
```

then render call

```
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_vbo_total, big_v_buff, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, big_ibo_total, big_i_buff,
                 GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sprite_count* 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

this draws to a blanks screen. I can't find out where I might be going wrong.

OK this is kinda crazy. I am using the gpuperf studio from amd to debug this but this leads to more confusion. I took two screenshots of the app running.

The profiler shows that the code should be rendering but for whatever reason it is not.

Here are the screenshots.
[image]
[image]

you can even see from the debugger that there's the two triangles where the quad is suppose to be. I have a very simplistic shader, all the data is getting to the gpu but for some reason it's not rendering correctly which is really confusing.

Now I really don't understand what's going on. Anyone have any advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to calling `glVertexAttribPointer` you also have to enable the vertex attribute by using `glEnableVertexAttribArray. In addition, the offset for the texture coordinates is wrong. They have to start at the 8th element, not at the 7th.

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                  (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                  (GLvoid*)(4 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                  (GLvoid*)(8 * sizeof(float)));
                            ^
```

Next thing: If you unbind the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` while the vao is still bound, it is removed from the vao state. Thus the disable has to happen in this order:

```
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Rendering: You unbind the vao after initializing the vertex attribute pointers, but it look as if you forgot to bind it before issuing the draw call.

Side-note: If the data of the VBO's is not changing in every frame, you should upload the data once during initialization and not in every frame.

Comment: I made all those edits and the code still draws a blank screen. The vertex can rotate and scale which can change every scene, also the amount of sprites are variable so the indices need to be updated as well. I though about ways to update only the parts that change but I can't even get interleaved vbo rendering working atm.

Comment: The amount of elements you draw looks strange. I'm not sure where the 144 comes from, but it should be the number of entries in the indexbuffer.

Comment: that 144 is actually a typo, i'll update that. It's sprite_count * vertex_count. Currently sprite count = 1 and vertex_count = 6 so it should only be rendering 1 quad or 2 triangles.

Comment: I just made some edits to the original question, this is really confusing me now!

Comment: Do you have backface culling enabled? If this is the case please check that the winding order is correct.